# Java : decode base64 string and create in-memory zip file and get files from that zip file java

Tags: java

Java: decode base64 string and create in-memory zip file and get files from that zip file java
While am trying with

```
enter code here

try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes))
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
======
====
}

while ((read = zipStream.read(bytesIn)) ==-1) {
baos.write(bytesIn, 0, read)
}
```

in while condition, it is giving an exception:
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bit difficult to know what you've missed out, but you've clearly got a few issues combined. Try to break your problem down: look at how to use the read() method properly to copy bytes from a file into an array. Once you've got that working, look at the details of ZipInputStream (I think you're missing a call to getNextEntry()), and check you can get that reading a known, good zip file from disk. Then once you've got that working, work on the problem of reliably decoding a Base 64 string into the correct byte sequence. Then plug that into your working zip reading code...

Comment: I don't know if that's literally what you wrote but it should probably be ```while ((read = zipStream.read(bytesIn)) > -1)```

Comment: while ((read = zipStream.read(bytesIn)) > -1) {
    baos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
   } 

It is giving Exception in zipStream.read(bytesIn) : java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back

Comment: Probably corrupt